# targetArray.reduce behavior when targetArray.length is changed in the reducer function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, ecmascript-5

This questions is primarily for those who work with the ECMAScript spec and/or implement it.

The [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) specifies the algorithm for `Array.prototype.reduce(callbackfn[,initialValue])`.
See that the algorithm, step 2, reads `Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length"))` and after that, my understanding is that `len` is never updated again.  However, take a look a this:

```
const a = [0,1,2,3,4];
a.reduce(p=>{
  a.splice(0,1);
  console.log(a);
  return p;
},a);
// Logs:
// [1,2,3,4]
// [2,3,4]
// [3,4]
// and that's it
```

Since the iterations are supposed to run `while k<len` (`k` being the iteration counter), this behavior suggests that, in the implementations I tried (Chrome, Edge, Node), `len` is being updated at each iteration to lenght of `a` of the current iteration.

Is that really the intended behavior?  Is there a concrete reason why `len` is purposely updated at each iteration instead of keeping it fixed from the start like specified in the spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is because of step 9.2: the callback is only called when the property is present on the object. It *does* iterate 5 times, but after you deleted 3 elements, in the fourth and fifth iteration `a.hasOwnProperty(3)` and `a.hasOwnProperty(4)` are false.

We can best demonstrate this with a proxy:

```js
const a = [0,1,2,3,4];
new Proxy(a, {
 has(target, p) { const v = Reflect.has(target, p); console.log("has", p, v); return v },
 get(target, p) { const v = Reflect.get(target, p); console.log("get", p, v); return v }
}).reduce((p, e) => {
  a.length--;
  console.log("at " + e, a);
  return p;
}, null);
```

Or alternatively by calling `reduce` on an object whose `.length` changes don't affect the properties:

```js
const a ={0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,length:5,reduce:Array.prototype.reduce};
a.reduce((p, e) => {
  a.length--;
  console.log("at " + e, a);
  return p;
}, null);
```